# Method parameters not formatted correctly in pdoc generated HTML

Tags: python, pdoc

I have a method in a class defined as shown below:

```
def my_method(self, a: str = None, b: str = None) -> typing.Set[str]:
    """
    Do something

    :param a: A string to represent something.

    :param b: A string to represent something else.

    :return: A set of strings.
    """

    return {a, b}
```

And pdoc generates the HTML in the picture below for that method:

[image]

What do I need to do to make pdoc generate something different for the `param` and `return` portions of the docstring?  Seems like *something* would be done by pdoc to differentiate params and return statements from each other in the docstring.  That something could be a highlight of the parameter and return statements, italic font, or bold font like seen below.  Whatever happens, I would like to see the text `:param` and `:return` removed from the docstring:

[image]

Comment: Can you please describe what do you want to achieve, i.e what is this _something diffferent_?

Comment: You want pdoc to include type hints maybe?

Comment: @sanyash, I added a new picture to my question to better describe what I'm expecting from pdoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after further clarity then you may try something like below

```
def my_method(self, a: str = None, b: str = None) -> typing.Set[str]:
    """
    Do something

    Args:
        a (str): The first parameter.
        b (str): The second parameter.

    Returns:
        Set: The return value. If result has values then Set of string, otherwise empty set.

    """
    s._parse_hh_mm_ss_ff()
    return {a, b}
```

[image: when called]

Comment: I would like to keep using the restructuredtext format.  Maybe that isn't possible.

Comment: @ubiquibacon, I am not sure on restructured text. Yo may check https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0287/

Comment: I think my answer is on the [pdoc website](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc/): `Common docstring formats: Out-of-the-box support for markdown, numpydoc, Google-style docstrings, Napoleon, and some common reST directives.`  Apparently "some common reST directives" doesn't include the ones I want to use.